# Continuity of $f_1$ and $f_2$ given continuity of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

I'm working on a problem which states the following:

Given the metric spaces $(X_1,d_1)$ and $(X_2,d_2)$, define the following

$$ X = X_1 \times X_2 \text{ with } d((x_1,x_2),(x^\prime_1,x^\prime_2) = d_1(x_1,x^\prime_1) +d_2(x_2,x^\prime_2).  $$

We also know that $(Y,d_y)$ is a metric space and that $(a_1,a_2)\in X$. Now consider the function $f:X \to Y$ and define $f_1:X_1 \to Y:x_1\mapsto f(x_1,a_2)$ and $f_2:X_2 \to Y:x_2\mapsto f(a_1,x_2)$.

a) Given that $f$ is continuous in $(a_1,a_2)$, are $f_1$ and $f_2$ continuous in $a_1$ and $a_2$ respectively?

b) What about the over direction?

I think both statements hold, but I am having trouble proving it. The notation confuses me a bit and I am running into issues. For part a), as I know that $f$ is continuous, given $\epsilon > 0$, for every $(x_1,x_2)\in X$ I can find a $\delta >0$ such that if $d((x_1,x_2),(a_1,a_2)) < \delta$ then $d_y(f(x_1,x_2),f(a_1,a_2)) < \epsilon$. From the definition of $d$ I know that $d((x_1,x_2),(a_1,a_2)) = d_1(x_1,a_1) + d_2(x_2,a_2) < \delta. $

I don't really know where to go from here, or if that is even the correct approach to the question. Can anyone give some advice on how to continue? For the opposite direction I don't really know how to begin. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous means that given $\epsilon>0$ ,$\exists\delta_{\epsilon}>0$ with

$d((x_1,x_2),(x_1',x_2'))<\delta_{\epsilon}\implies d_Y(f(x_1,x_2),f(x_1',x_2'))<\epsilon $

Thus, if we want $d_Y(f_1(x_1),f_1(x_1'))<\epsilon$ we may set $d_1(x_1,x_1')<\delta_{\epsilon}$ and then $d((x_1,a_2),(x_1',a_2))=d_1(x_1,x_1')<\delta_{\epsilon}$ and we'd get

$d_Y(f_1(x_1),f_1(x_1'))=d_Y(f(x_1,a_2),f(x_1',a_2))<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous indeed. Given $x_1\in X_1$ and $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta>0$ such that $d\bigl((x_1,a_1),(x,y)\bigr)<\delta\implies d_y\bigl(f(x_1,a_1),f(x,y)\bigr)<\varepsilon$. Then\begin{align}d_1(x_1,x)<\delta&\iff d\bigl((x_1,a_1),(x,a_1)\bigr)<\delta\\&\implies d_y\bigl(f_1(x_1),f_1(x)\bigr)<\varepsilon.\end{align}
In the other direction, it is false. Take $X_1=X_2=\Bbb R$, $a_1=a_2=0$, and$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x=0\text{ or }y=0\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $f$ is discontinuous, but $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous.